# Render a select box in custom views field plugin hadler

Tags: views, 8

I have created a custom field plugin handler. In `render()` function I want to render a select box. I tried using a renderable array but it strips HTML `<select>` and `<option>` tag. If I return a string entire HTML is printed as a string. 
Normal HTML tags like `<div>` or `<ul>` works fine but input elements or select box are stripped out.

Please help.